# Nice way to create new arrays from provided array with determined length without start with 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I think I achieve my goal but I'm sure that it is not the best approach to do it.
I have a function and there is a issue that make it to add some extra [0], I got that is because the while test keep going. I don't need to do it with while+splice. I would like some suggestion to make it easier. My goal is from a provided array, create new arrays always starting from a element different from 0 and the length will be provided as k:

```
function splitNumber(arrayProvided, k) {
  let newArray = [];

  while (arrayProvided.length > 0) {
    newArray.push(
      arrayProvided.splice(
        arrayProvided.findIndex(el => el),
        k
      )
    );
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(
  splitNumber([1, 0, 4, 6, 0, 7, 8, 4, 2, 0, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6], 4)
);
```

The result for this code is:

```
[
  [ 1, 0 ], [ 4, 6 ],
  [ 7, 8 ], [ 4, 2 ],
  [ 8, 3 ],    [ 6 ],
     [ 0 ],    [ 0 ],
     [ 0 ],    [ 0 ],
     [ 0 ],    [ 0 ],
     [ 0 ],    [ 0 ],
     [ 0 ]
]
```

It's correctly partially because the system is having a extra working after the job done adding extra [0]. The system cannot start with a 0 value in the first array position and no need extra [0] (It's happens because the logic is not totally right), and Yes the lenght of the new arrays is the k value.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to populate an array of length `K` using random items from a given array?

Comment: do you want to keep the last zeroes or not? please add the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without zeroes, you could add another check and omit unwanted zeroes.

This approach does **not mutate** the given data.

```js
function splitNumber(array, k) {
    let result = [],
        i = 0;

    while (i < array.length) {
        if (array[i] === 0) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        result.push(array.slice(i, i += k));
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(splitNumber([1, 0, 4, 6, 0, 7, 8, 4, 2, 0, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6], 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its already a pretty smart solution to use `findIndex` to implicitly check for non-zero indeces. However, you need to handle when it returns `-1` as is the case when no non-zero entries was found. So putting a check for that solves your issue.

```
function splitNumber(arrayProvided, k) {
  let newArray = [];

  while (arrayProvided.length > 0) {
    let nonZeroStartIndex = arrayProvided.findIndex(el => el )
    if( nonZeroStartIndex == -1 ){
      break; 
    }
    else{
      newArray.push(
        arrayProvided.splice( nonZeroStartIndex , k )
        );
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(
  splitNumber([1, 0, 4, 6, 0, 7, 8, 4, 2, 0, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6], 4)
);
```

Then, the check can be moved up to the `while` loop to let it gracefully exit when no more non-zero entries can be found

```
function splitNumber(arrayProvided, k) {
  let newArray = [];
  let nonZeroStartIndex = arrayProvided.findIndex(el => el )
  while (nonZeroStartIndex != -1) {
    newArray.push( arrayProvided.splice( nonZeroStartIndex, k ) );
    nonZeroStartIndex = arrayProvided.findIndex(el => el )
    }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(
  splitNumber([1, 0, 4, 6, 0, 7, 8, 4, 2, 0, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6], 4)
);
```